# Excel Formula to concat multiple columns with years given start year and end year

Tags: excel

I have excel like this, I would like to concat the Static Column with range of year with given start year and end year like below:

| Make | Model | Start Year | End Year | CONCAT RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota | Camry | 2005 | 2008 | Toyota Camry 2005,Toyota Camry 2006,Toyota Camry 2007,Toyota Camry 2008 |
| Honda | Civic | 2007 | 2008 | Honda Civic 2007,Honda Civic 2008 |

Please help

Comment: What version do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For older version from 2019:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,A2&" "&B2&" "&ROW(INDIRECT(C2&":"&D2)))
```

array formula to confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER,
bye.

Comment: Thanks.  Work Perfect for LibreOffice

Answer (score 2):

Using TEXTJOIN and SEQUENCE:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,A2&" "&B2&" "&SEQUENCE(D2-C2+1,,C2))
```

[image]

Comment: I am sure it will work on Excel but LibreOffice Calc doesn't carry Sequence Function.  Thanks

Comment: @LongLe then why did you tag it as Excel?  Please next time tag it with what you are using.  As you see Excel and LibreOffice are not the same thing.